# Double-Click Handler in KendoUI Angular2 Grid

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I have found a couple of forum posts that explain how to add a double-click handler to the KendoUI Grid using AngularJS, but I cannot find anything with respect to Angular2. Does anyone know how to create a double-click handler for the KendoUI Grid in Angular2?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `dblclick` event handler to the grid:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" (dblclick)="doubleClickHandler($event)">
</kendo-grid>

public doubleClickHandler(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
}
```

You can then use jquery `closest` to get the cell or row that was double-clicked:

```
let row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
let cell = $(e.target).closest("td");
```

You might want to filter the results after that to make sure the double-click wasn't on the header and such.